# Django - How to run a function inside a constructor?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models, constructor

As far as I've read, overriding the **init** function is not recommended in Django. Then how can I assign value to "hashed" and "salt"? They will not have the value of the original text, there are functions named `def createSalt(self):` and `def createHash(self, salt, password):` that will take the original text and convert it to something different. I tried this in model class but it didn't work: (it probably looks stupid )

```
salt = models.TextField(createSalt())
```

or

```
salt = models.TextField(createSalt(self))
```

Another suggestion was to define a new function named create and use it like a constructor. But then it's not really a constructor, is it?

Here is my model:

```
class User(models.Model):
        username = models.CharField(db.String(100), primary_key=True)
        hashed = models.TextField()
        salt = models.TextField()
```

Comment: The second suggestion you list is one of the ones that the Django docs recommend in cases like this - https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/instances/#creating-objects, if that helps.

Comment: @bouteillebleu I decided to add a method on a custom manager. Not sure if that's the best way though. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure can you take this as an example?

```
import uuid
```

...

```
uuid = models.UUIDField(unique=True, default=uuid.uuid1, null=True, blank=True)
```

here the uuid.uuid1 is just a method, not called.

```
def uuid1(node=None, clock_seq=None):
    """Generate a UUID from a host ID, sequence number, and the current time.
    If 'node' is not given, getnode() is used to obtain the hardware
    address.  If 'clock_seq' is given, it is used as the sequence number;
    otherwise a random 14-bit sequence number is chosen."""

    # When the system provides a version-1 UUID generator, use it (but don't
    # use UuidCreate here because its UUIDs don't conform to RFC 4122).
    if _uuid_generate_time and node is clock_seq is None:
        _buffer = ctypes.create_string_buffer(16)
        _uuid_generate_time(_buffer)
        return UUID(bytes=bytes_(_buffer.raw))

    global _last_timestamp
    import time
    nanoseconds = int(time.time() * 1e9)
    # 0x01b21dd213814000 is the number of 100-ns intervals between the
    # UUID epoch 1582-10-15 00:00:00 and the Unix epoch 1970-01-01 00:00:00.
    timestamp = int(nanoseconds/100) + 0x01b21dd213814000
    if _last_timestamp is not None and timestamp <= _last_timestamp:
        timestamp = _last_timestamp + 1
    _last_timestamp = timestamp
    if clock_seq is None:
        import random
        clock_seq = random.randrange(1<<14) # instead of stable storage
    time_low = timestamp & 0xffffffff
    time_mid = (timestamp >> 32) & 0xffff
    time_hi_version = (timestamp >> 48) & 0x0fff
    clock_seq_low = clock_seq & 0xff
    clock_seq_hi_variant = (clock_seq >> 8) & 0x3f
    if node is None:
        node = getnode()
    return UUID(fields=(time_low, time_mid, time_hi_version,
                        clock_seq_hi_variant, clock_seq_low, node), version=1)
```